# RegEx for Javascript to strict alphanumeric with optional space charecter

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a reg ex that only allows alphanumeric. It should accept only alphanumeric characters alone. I am trying below regex and its passing all the cases except optional space .

```
dGgs1s23 - valid

12fUgdf  - valid,

123 abc  - Invalid,

121232   - invalid,

abchfe   - invalid,

 abd()*  - invalid, 

42232^5$ - invalid
```

The Regex is handling all cases except "abc 123" where there is space in between.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Can someone suggest modification to above regex?

Important: Optional space character should be allowed along with strict alphanumeric input.

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com).

Comment: Can't reproduce--looks like your regex successfully rejects `123 abc` on regex101 and matches your expectations for everything else. Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: The regex  to have an optional spaces is just `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[ a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: If you require the space(s) to be in the middle, where it is a single space, it is this `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$` or if it's many spaces in the middle it is this `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9](?: +[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this expression would validate our desired data:

```
^(?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)([a-z0-9]+|[a-z]+\s[0-9]+)$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5beuV2/1/)

#### TEST

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)([a-z0-9]+|[a-z]+\s[0-9]+)$/gmi;
const str = `dGgs1s23
12fUgdf
abcd1
1abcd
abc 123

abc  123
123 abc
121232
abchfe
abd()*
42232^5\$`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```